# Poles and singularity confusion.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity, singular-values

I've two complex functions:

1) $f(z) = \frac 1 {\sin(πz^2)}$.

It has simple poles at $ z = \sqrt n$ for all integers $n$ except $0$.

2) $f(z) = \frac z {\sin πz^2}.$

It has poles of order two at $z = \sqrt n$ for all integers $n$ except $0$.

I've tried Laurent series expansion, and residue formation, but I can't prove the results. Although I've proved for $z=0$.

Please guide me through this problem. What might I be missing?

Comment: I don't think part 2) is right. This function also has simple poles at $\sqrt {n}$.

Comment: actually it is, from a standard question asked in a competitive exam.

Comment: $\lim _{z \to 1} (z-1)f(z)=\frac 1 {-2\pi}$ which proves the pole at $z=\sqrt 1$ is of order $1$.

Comment: In 1), the pole at $0$ is of order $2$, all other poles (at $\pm \sqrt{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$) are simple. In 2) all poles (at $\pm \sqrt{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$) are simple. Multiplying with $z$ reduces the order of the pole at $0$ by $1$ and leaves all other pole orders unaffected (just changes the residue).

Comment: There is no option as such, which proves the statement about part (c). Are you sure that Laurent series expansion about z=1 would lead similar results?